# How to use FindDevIL cmake macro

Tags: cmake

I found this macro: http://www.mail-archive.com/cmake@cmake.org/msg17189.html
And want to use it.

I added a directory cmake/modules to my project and put FindDevIL.cmake into that directory.
Than I added:

```
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules)
FindDevIL()
```

to my main CMakeLists.txt. Now I get:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:53 (FindDevIL):
Unknown CMake command "FindDevIL".
```

How do I do it right?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find_package(DevIL)